# Case statement with Null value and Integer

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following test use case which is working fine:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 as id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2
)

Select 
  *,
  case when id is null then "null" when id = 1 then "test" end
from 
  t1
```

On my real query I have a date_diff function:

```
DATE_DIFF(second_date,first_date, DAY) as time_lag,
```

and when trying to apply the following case statement:

```
case when time_lag is null then "null" when time_lag = "1" then "test" end
```

I have this error:

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRUCT<client_ID STRING, Total INT64, first_date DATE, ...>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [79:49]
```

From what I understand the DATE_DIFF statement is returning `INT64` and some null values as not all the row contain date. I don't understand how my test use case is different from my real use case. and What's wrong with my real use case...

Comment: Have you tried  "CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(second_date,first_date, DAY) is null THEN  null WHEN DATE_DIFF(second_date,first_date, DAY) = 1 then 'Test' end"  .

Comment: @VarunT Yes It is working... I don't understand why but It's working....

Comment: @Simon Breton, Can you share the real case query?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
case when time_lag is null then "null" when time_lag = 1 then "test" end
```

as you said  - time_lag is INT64 so the problem is/was in `... when time_lag = "1" then ...`

Comment: Same error `No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRUCT<client_ID STRING, Total INT64, first_date DATE, ...>, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [83:49]`

Comment: then you should update your question with your real query so we can help you!!

Comment: I'm on it. It is a very very big query.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, You are treating time_lag as a column in the database table which I guess, it is not. It is a calculated value from 2 columns. So you have 2 choices - either use a subquery which does the DATE_DIFF operation and then alias it as time_lag. Or use the calculation directly in case expression.

```
 CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(second_date,first_date, DAY) is null THEN null WHEN DATE_DIFF(second_date,first_date, DAY) = 1 then 'Test' end
```

Comment: I'm using a sub-query. Which I don't understand is that why It is working on the main query and not working when applied to the result in the sub-query.

Comment: Well, I would need to see what sub-query you are using.

Comment: yes. It is part of the very big query so I'm trying to see how I can share it here.